# How do I set the dimensions of a window on the primary screen to the dimensions of the external monitor?

Tags: scripting

While using extended monitors, I need to a script that:

1. Gets the dimensions of the external monitor (connected to HDMI1)
2. Set the dimensions of the current window on the primary monitor to match.

I know I can use `xdotool getwindowfocus` to identify the currently focused window, but couldn't figure out how to do the rest.

Comment: What are the dimensions involved? Is your external monitor as large or smaller than your primary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get information about connected monitors with [`xrandr`](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.xhtml). It doesn't have a convenient query format, you need to run it without arguments and parse the output.

You can use [`xdotool`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/xdotool.1.html) to do a number of things with windows, including querying and changing their attributes such as focus and size. You can use [command chaining](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/xdotool.1.html#command%20chaining) to act on a window without having to explicitly obtain its window id, for example `xdotool getactivewindow dostuff …` to apply the `dostuff` command to the window that has the focus.

```
#!/bin/sh
monitor='HDMI-1'
new_xy=$(xrandr | sed -n "s/^$monitor [^ ]* \([0-9]*\)x\([0-9]*\).*/\1 \2/p")
if [ -n "$new_xy" ]; then
  xdotool getwindowfocus $new_xy
fi # else $monitor is not active
```

Note that the window size includes decorations (title bar, borders), so this makes the full window including decorations actually not fit on the monitor.

If you also want to move the window to HDMI-1, you can parse the coordinates of the monitor from the same line of the `xrandr` output. But then rather than resize the window, you'd probably want to maximize it or make it full screen. The difference between maximization/full-screen and resizing to the screen size is that the window manager remembers the non-maximized size of the window and has a command to restore it. Maximization keeps decorations around the window whereas full-screen doesn't. Maximization and full-screen are window manager concepts, not X server concepts, and xdotool can't do it. Right off the bat I can't think of a window-manager-agnostic way to do it.